# I keep getting a NoSuchElementException in selenium even though the element DOES exist

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is my first scraping project using selenium. I'm trying to download a couple of reddit videos saved in a list using [this website](https://keepv.id/reddit-video-downloader).

As you can see, it shows an input tag where I need to enter the url of the video or gif then go to the download page. That input tag has a class name `form-control form-control-lg form-control-alternative`. So when I try getting that element so I can fill it with a link from a list in Python, it shows a `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .form-control form-control-lg form-control-alternative` error.

You can check yourselves using the Developer Tools and you'll see that that input tag has that class.

Here's my code:

```
for gif in gif_list:
    driver.get('https://keepv.id/reddit-video-downloader')
    input_tag = driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control form-control-lg form-control-alternative')
    input_tag.send_keys(gif)
    go_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-danger')
    go_button.click()
    second_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-danger sheen waggle spin')
    second_button.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'row')))
    download_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-danger mb-3 shadow vdlbtn')
    download_button.click()
    gif_url = driver.current_url()
    download_gif(gif_url)
```

Comment: You shouldn't find elements by class name if the class name has spaces in it.  Maybe try a different selector/approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name()` accept single class only  use `css selector` instead.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form-control.form-control-lg.form-control-alternative").send_keys(gif)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-danger").click()
```

Or you can use by_id

```
driver.find_element_by_id("dlURL").send_keys(gif)
driver.find_element_by_id("dlBTN1").click()
```

---

Ideally you should use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selecor

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".form-control.form-control-lg.form-control-alternative"))).send_keys(gif)
```

To click go button

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn.btn-danger"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thx, I fixed the ones you told me about but when you go back to my code there's a line where i get the download_button element. For some reason i keep getting that same nosuchelement error even after I tried changing to the css selector and modifying the string. I even tried with the xpath after copying it using the developer tools and getting '/html/body/main/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a'.